# In Python, is there a way to make argparse sub-commands case insensitive?

Tags: python, argparse

From https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands, is there a way to make the `add_parser` commands case insensitive?

E.g. I want to be able to read a sensor using 'read_sensor' or 'READ_SENSOR', for example.

I know we can make `add_argument()` commands case insensitive using the type parameter, but the `add_parser` command does not have a type parameter..

Comment: If `aliases` aren't enough, you could [sneakily swap out the implementation of `_name_parser_map` in the subparsers object](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/argparse.py#L1202) for a case-insensitive dict...

Comment: Thanks, I think using aliases is enough and avoids modifying argparse source code.

Comment: Feel free to post your comment as an answer and I'll accept ;)